# Trying to play multiple videos in wpf but it only took the last video

Tags: c#

I don't know if i am doing it correctly.
Here I'm trying to play all the videos from the video folder in wpf C# but it only plays the last video , how can i fix this

```
        // Go to video folder.
        var videosFolder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;  

        // Here i get all  the files in the video folder.  
        var files = await videosFolder.GetFilesAsync(); 

        // If there is no file do nothing.
        if (files.Count == 0)  
        {  
            return;  
        }  

        // Here i  am looping all the videos.
        foreach (var video in files)  
        {  
            // Accessing each file in the video folder.
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(video.Path);  
           // ...
            if (file == null)   
            {  
                return;  
            } 

            // Getting the path of a file.
            var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file); 

            // ... 
            VideoPlayer.SetPlaybackSource(source);  
        }
```

Comment: What is this `VideoPlayer`? Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: media element form xaml ,sorry for that.

Comment: I don't see [`System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement) having `SetPlaybackSource` method

Comment: Everything its working , it is just the loop it doesn't wait for the video to finish playing before continuing looping and Thread.Sleep() doesn't work but i did include system.Threading namespace

Comment: I insist on the type because I suspect it should have some interface (async method or an event) you could use to let you know when it's done playing, but we can't know about it since we don't know the exact type

Comment: @Thembalethu what is `VideoPlayer`? Is it a 3rd-party library? Check if it has any events like `OnVideoCompleted` or anything like that, and then put your next file playback code there.

Answer (score 2):

You are not waiting for each video to complete before starting to play the next one. This is why you only see the last one actually play.

Comment: i've tried to use Thread.Sleep(duration) i get an error but i did include system.threading

Comment: Thanx now its working i created a container called "MediaPlaybackList mediaPlaybackList;" where i can store all the " MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem;" then after the loop " VideoPlayer.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlaybackList);" .. ..Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to subscribe to `MediaEnded` event from [MediaElement documentations:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaended)

> Occurs when the MediaElement finishes playing audio or video.

Here is a sample code (not tested!):

```
// subscribe once
VideoPlayer.MediaEnded += OnMediaEnded;

private void OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var nextMediaSource = GetNextMediaSource();
    if(nextMediaSource != null)
        VideoPlayer.SetPlaybackSource(nextMediaSource);
}
```

Comment: Thanx now its working i created a container called  "MediaPlaybackList mediaPlaybackList;" where i can store all the " MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem;" then after the loop " VideoPlayer.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlaybackList);" .. ..Thank you guys for your help

Comment: @Thembalethu I'm glad to hear that. If you found my answer useful, please mark it as answer :)